# Unable to install hotfix to solve Search web part error?

Tags: web-part, search, error

This is the exception I get when I do a basic search:

> CoreResultsWebPart::OnInit: Exception initializing:
>   System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance
>   of an object.
>   at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.WebControls.CoreResultsWebPart.SetPropertiesOnQueryReader()
>   at
>   Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.WebControls.CoreResultsWebPart.OnInit(EventArgs e)

From what I see from various blog posts and articles this can be fixed with **[KB976462](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/976462)** hotfix but not for me. I can't install the hotfix because the installation doesn't even start and gives this message: "**The update is not applicable to your computer"**.

Search service application is running smoothly and crawls without problems and over 40.000 items are all indexed.

What should I do?

Comment: Is this question related to your other search question? http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/16784/we-did-not-find-any-results-for-criteria Or is that a different farm?

Comment: No they are not related. That's completely a different problem.

Comment: What server OS are you using? I'm assuming Windows 7 or Windows Server 2008 R2?

Comment: Hi Kit. SP runs on Windows Server 2008 R2.

Comment: Do you have SP1 of .NET 3.5 installed?

Answer (score 1):

Did you download the correct package (x64)?

You can check the files listed in the KB for the associated version numbers.  If they are = or > KB listing you wont be able to deploy the package, and you probably already have it installed.  You should be able to remove the KB and then re-install it.

If they are lower, you can try and extract the package contents and force them to install, or download [process monitor](http://live.sysinternals.com/Procmon.exe) run it while installing the package and see what it is looking for (probably a reg key).  You could then remove the regkey and then attempt the install again.

Alternatively, You may want to try running these two PowerShell commands and see if that clears up your issue:

Initialize-SPResourceSecurity

Install-SPFeature -AllExistingFeatures

Sometime the obvious gets overlooked, ensure your Search features are available and enabled on the site you are accessing from.