# We did not find any results for "criteria"

Tags: search

I've set up search and all the items are crawled and now there are a total of 40.000 items in the store.

I do a basic search but no result are returned from the query. I am sure that there are lots of items that has the title same as my search criteria but Search can't find anything.

Any help is greatly appreciated, it's been 4 hours I am working on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my answer to this question:

Just do not forget to disable loopback check when installing SharePoint 2010.

http://www.harbar.net/archive/2009/07/02/disableloopbackcheck-amp-sharepoint-what-every-admin-and-developer-should-know.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Have you set up your "search center". The default search box may still be set to a contextual scope. You also need to configure search in your site collection settings.

Just throwing out guesses here, as you don't tell us much about what you have done.

Comment: Hi SPDoctor. I got a little progress here. So the current situation is this: On the server there are 3 web applications. Search service indexes only one of these apps. I created 3 different content sources but two of them gives "Access denied" crawl errors. They shouldn't be because the account that the crawl process runs has Full Read on both of the apps.

Comment: Okay, now we moved from a "content is indexed but can't query" situation to a "can't crawl content" problem, rendering my answer irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

If I enter something in search box then click search button.

> we did not find any results for

is displayed. how to solve this problem.

Comment: You need to post this as a question not as an answer ;)